# Should the vCard microformat property 'country-name' be in the language of the website?

Tags: html, localization, seo, microformats, hcard

I have following code on my website:

```
<address class="vcard">
  <span class="fn org"></span><br>
  <span class="adr"><br>
    <span class="street-address"></span><br>
    <span class="locality"></span>, <span class="region"></span><br>
    <span class="postal-code"></span><br>
    <span class="country-name">Nederland</span><br>
  </span><br>
</address>
```

As you can see the `country-name` contains **`Nederland`** which is Dutch for **the Netherlands**. Should this always be specified in the language of the website, for search engines to recognize? Or is this only readable in English?

Because it displays on the site it should be in the language of the website, but I am questioning whether or not this is effective to SEO.

Comment: For non-programming SEO questions, please ask them over on [webmasters.se]

Comment: Apart from "whether or not this is effective to SEO", this question would be on-topic here. But you’ve given the correct answer yourself: "Because it displays on the site it should be in the language of the website".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Comment: there is a tag for seo on this site. how is seo off topic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused because there is no other data displayed in the hcard, but I think I get the gist of what you are saying. If the language you are using, for any content, differs from the language you have declared in the `lang` attribute on the `body` element, yes, use the `lang` attribute also on an element wrapping that content, declaring the language that content is in.
So if your site is in Dutch or Danish (apologies for not knowing) and then you specify `Nederland`, you do not need to redeclare the language, but if the site is in any language other than one where `Nederland` is native, then you should redeclare the language of the attribute.